# Why `find . -iname *.blend` does not find all blend files in external exFAT storage?

Tags: terminal, finder

When I issue the command

```
find . -iname *.blend
```

I get only one result (which is in the pwd). Adding `-maxdepth 5` does not help either.

On the other hand `find . | grep \.blend$` returns a lot of results (actually the tens of blend files in my tree)

Why is that? What can I do to fix it?

> Additional, maybe irrelevant information is that finder does not find anything at all when searching this drive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell expands `*.blend` before calling `find` *if* there is a matching file in the current directory.

Use

```
find . -iname '*.blend'
```

instead